# How to setup NetBeans IDE for Python Development

Tags: python, java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-12

I was using PyDev plugin in eclipse for developing python. But now I switched to **NetBeans IDE 12.6** and I searched google for finding python plugins for NetBeans. I found a plugin called [nbpython](http://nbpython.org/).
But it is for NetBeans 8.1 and I am using NetBeans 12.6. So is there any plugin for NetBeans IDE 12.6 for developing Python Projects. Or does nbpython work in my version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new plugin for python is netbeansPython:

https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/catalogue/?id=89

https://github.com/albilu/netbeansPython

Answer (score 5):

There is no official plugin for 12.x yet. If you read on the [mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@netbeans.apache.org:lte=1y:python) you can see that a re-implementation of the Python support was discussed but nothing has been implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I just installed Netbeans IDE v 13. I had since long time ago the Python/Jython/PERL modules for Netbeans 8.xx Which worked for a long time. For IDE v 13 I added them via the usual method, "Tools -> Plugins -> Downloaded -> Add Plugins", and it looks like they work fine! Therefore their compatibility with Apache Netbeans is very high. The problem is with the links of nbpython, they look broken & discontinued. If one has the old modules posted somewhere, then I guess you can pick those up and feel lucky. If not, you need to find them somehow, or wait for the python project to be re-implemented. The modules I have are described below. Hope this helps:

> org-netbeans-modules-python-hints.nbm
> org-netbeans-modules-python-kit.nbm
> org-netbeans-modules-python-options.nbm
> org-netbeans-modules-python-platform.nbm
> org-netbeans-modules-python-project.nbm
> org-netbeans-modules-python-project2.nbm
> org-netbeans-modules-python-samples.nbm
> org-netbeans-modules-python-source.nbm
> org-netbeans-modules-python-testrunner.nbm   org-jython.nbm
> org-jython-distro.nbm   org-netbeans-modules-python-console.nbm
> org-netbeans-modules-python-core.nbm
> org-netbeans-modules-python-debugger.nbm
> org-netbeans-modules-python-editor.nbm
> org-netbeans-modules-python-help.nbm

Comment: Do have any link to download these

Comment: Maybe this one??
https://github.com/GeertjanWielenga/Python4NetBeans/tree/master/PythonSuite/binaries